# swift: why I get a str type in the dict

Tags: swift

```
var hash = Dictionary<Int,Any>()

hash[11] = ["1111","22222"]

println(hash)


for (key,value) in hash{
    print("key:\(key) , hi")

    print(value)
    for i in [value] {
        print(" ggg \(i)")
    }

}
```

I just test on the dict in swift and have a question like this. After I store array ["1111","2222"] in the hash, finally I get the str type of "["1111","2222"]" . Can someone help?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you want is:

```
for (key,value) in hash {
    if let vals = value as? Array<String> {
        for str in vals {
            print("string: \(str)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not likely, there will be an error in "for i in vals".